# Unable to click on apps on the home page of a dynamics web application

Tags: dynamics-crm

[this is the screenshot of what i'm trying to click on](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dbaRG.png)Below is the problem i'm facing while clicking an element(one of the apps) on the dynamics home page.

I tried finding the element using xpath, relative xpath and a few other methods, but it doesnt seem to find the element.

Here is the code for finding the element and clicking on it.

Feature file code :
Feature: Dynamics Login

Scenario: Dynamics Login

Given user "int 1"
When navigate to "Apps"
Then start "Customer and Stakeholder Hub"

Step definition file:

```
And(/^start "(.*?)"$/) do |linkname|
  sleep 5
  #txpath = "//iframe[@id='AppLandingPage']//div[contains(text(),'"+linkname+"')]"
   txpath= "//div[contains(text(),'"+linkname+"')]"
        wait_until(:xpath, txpath, 60)
    @driver.find_element(:xpath, txpath).click
    #wait_until(:xpath, "//h1[contains(text(),'"+linkname+"')]", 60)
    sleep $AutoSleep
end
```

Comment: could you add some screenshot what you are trying to achieve. This will be easier to deal with your question.

Comment: Attached a screenshot of what I'm trying to click on. Can you please check now

Comment: are you aware of Power automate and specifically RPA especially [Create and test Selenium IDE flows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-automate/desktop-flows/create-web) This does use selenium and perform automation, once you use this in one of the step you will find the path to your correct click